# Show that $\int\limits_0^x \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}2\right)dt = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f(x) = x+\dfrac{x^3}{1\cdot 3} + \dfrac{x^5}{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5} + \dfrac{x^7}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}+\dots$ and let $g(x) = 1+\dfrac{x^2}{2} + \dfrac{x^4}{2\cdot 4} + \dfrac{x^6}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6} + \dots$ Show that $\displaystyle\int_0^x \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}2\right)dt = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$

I was thinking of finding a closed form for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ but I couldn't do that (I did get that $\sinh(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}$ and $\cosh(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^{2i}}{(2i)!}$).

> Edit: Apparently I need to differentiate both sides and show that they vanish at $0$.

Comment: Take derivative on both sides and prove the identity for the derivatives. Both sides vanish at $x=0$.

Comment: Not just from the equality of the derivatives, but one also needs to check that they coincide at a point. In this case $x=0$ is easy to check.

Comment: The vanishing at $x=0$ is clear, since $\int_{0}^{0}e^{-t^2/2}=0=\frac{f(0)}{g(0)}$. So, what remains to be proven is that $e^{-x^2/2}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)}{g^2(x)}$. Now, note that $g(x)=e^{x^2/2}$, $g'(x)=xg(x)$ and that $f'(x)-1=xf(x)$. Therefore, $e^{-x^2/2}=\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{g(x)}{g^2(x)}=\frac{(1+xf(x))g(x)-xf(x)g(x)}{g^2(x)}=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)}{g^2(x)}$.

Comment: Just for your curiosity : $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ and $g(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, here is the naive/systematic approach.

Let

$$n!!=\begin{cases}n\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-4)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1 & \textrm{if } n>0 \\ 1 & \textrm{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Then we have
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!!}, \qquad f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n-1)!!}$$
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!!}, \qquad g'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-2)!!}$$

The cross-products with the derivatives are

$$f'(x)g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{(2n+2m)}}{(2n-1)!!(2m)!!}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{2i}\left(\sum_{n=0}^i \frac{1}{(2n-1)!!(2i-2n)!!}\right)$$

$$g'(x)f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{x^{(2k+2m)}}{(2k-2)!!(2m+1)!!}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{2i}\left(\sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{(2k-2)!!(2i-2k+1)!!}\right).$$

where I made the changes of variables $i=n+m$ (first line) and $i=k+m$ (second line). Note that, for a fixed $i$, the $n$-th term of the inner sum in $f'(x)g(x)$ is equal to the term with $k=i-n+1$ in $g'(x)f(x)$. This means that, when computing $f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)$, all terms in the inner sums will cancel except the term with $n=0$ in $f'(x)g(x)$ (which requires $k=i+1$, which is not in $g'(x)f(x)$). Therefore,

$$f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{2i}\frac{1}{(2i)!!}=g(x)$$

which turns out to be equal to $g(x)$. Then,

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g(x)^2}=\frac{1}{g(x)}.$$

On the other hand, it is easy to see that $(2i)!!=i! 2^i$, and therefore

$$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2i}}{2^i}\frac{1}{i!}=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}.$$

This means that 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2}=e^{-x^2/2}=\frac{1}{g(x)}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

As pointed out by MoonLightSyzygy in the comments, the equality of the derivatives, together with the fact that both sides are equal at $x=0$, proves that both functions are equal:

$$\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2}=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f^\prime+xf=1$, integration factors tell us a constant $c$ exists for which $f=\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot\int_c^x\exp\frac{t^2}{2}dt$. Since $f(0)=0$, $c=0$. The desired claim then follows from $g=\exp\frac{x^2}{2}$.

Comment: I like this approach best, but think it'd be best expanded upon. First off, if $f(x)=e^{x^2/2}\int_0^x e^{-t^2/2}dt$, which is an a priori natural thing to consider given a knowledge of how solutions of the integrating factor method wind up looking like, then we get the differential equation $f'-xf=1$ from applying the product rule to the relation $\int_0^xe^{-t^2/2}dt=e^{-x^2/2}f(x)$, plus an initial condition $f(0)=0$, and then we can write a power series for $f$ and solve its coefficients by plugging them into the differential equation.